# presentViewController is not working when the first time application launch

Tags: ios

I am facing this weird problem. I have a simple piece of code that is supposed to work fine but it doesn't work when first time launching the app. It works perfectly fine when I run the application second time.

And by the way the following code is used to open the application and display a viewController when i tap the today view widget:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
  OverviewDetailVC *overViewDetail = (OverviewDetailVC *)initViewController;
  overViewDetail.productDetail = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:FetchRequest error:nil];
  overViewDetail.productName = [overViewDetail.productDetail[0] valueForKey:@"generic"];        
  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:overViewDetail animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: From above why do you need to use handleOpenURL for launching the application first time?

Comment: I am using it to open the app when i tap the today view widget.

Comment: I am asking why did you put your code inside the handleOpenURL method?

Comment: Where should i put it then?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

{

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"secondshowPushNotification" object:nil];
    });

}

FirstView controller:

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showCompanyFromPushNotification:) name:@"secondshowPushNotification" object:nil];

}

-(void)showCompanyFromPushNotification:(NSNotification*)notification

{

[self.rootController presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

// it open's secondViewController.